# How to fix "Sorry, this type of video cannot be saved to this device"?

Tags: dropbox, instagram

In order to share my videos on Instagram, I export them to a file, sync to Dropbox, open my iOS 12.4.8 device, save from Dropbox to the device Photo Gallery, open Instagram, and share the file on Instagram. This has worked for other videos made by DaVinci Resolve and iMovie.

On the iOS Dropbox app, I click on the file, then `Share`, `Export file`, `Save video` and see this error:

```
Couldn't save

Sorry, this type of video cannot be saved to this device.
```

I restarted the phone, I exported in `.mov` and `.mp4` and I get the same error. With a previous video exported from DaVinci Resolve, I was able to save it and share to the Instagram app. But this video I cannot, so I assume that the error is on the Dropbox side.

For reference, here are the export settings on DaVinci Resolve:

[image: export settings]

How can I use Dropbox to save the online file to the iOS device?

Answer (score 1):

https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/photos/video-length

https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/sort-preview/file-types-that-preview

Assuming you've familiarized yourself with the limitations/restrictions in regards to video and audio format and size for Dropbox in the above links, you may need to check the integrity of the file that you're trying to share/send (either unsupported format or bad file-integrity compromised).  If it truly is a Dropbox issue (especially with their app), then you may need to pursue this issue with their support department.  Good luck.

Comment: I checked the links and confirm that the file respects the limitations (`.mov` and `.mp4` format, less than 50 MB, as a Dropbox Basic user, but I'm not trying to preview it nor to play it). I tried multiple times with different versions of the file and get the same error. Yes, I will try Dropbox's support department.